# decode xml string in php

Tags: php, xml, decode, urldecode

I want to decode this xml string

```
$string= "%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%20%3CPrintStudentData%20%20name%3D%22John%20Doe%22%20marks%3D%2298%22%20%2F%3E";
```

I tried  `echo urldecode($string);`  but it is not printing anything.

**Expected Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <PrintStudentData  name="John Doe" marks="98" />
```

Comment: Wfm? https://3v4l.org/YFmCi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Michael Scofield just add header("Content-Type: application/xml") to get your desired output like below code, because you have to tell browser that i am going to see xml type content and by that header("Content-Type: application/xml") you can able to see the xml output in the browser:

```
<?php
$string = "%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%20%3CPrintStudentData%20%20name%3D%22John%20Doe%22%20marks%3D%2298%22%20%2F%3E";
$xml = urldecode ($string);
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
echo $xml;
```

Comment: Oops My bad!,I forgot the headers! 
Thanks @jon,@clearshot66,@bunkerboy for your quick reply!

Comment: if this is your right answer so please mark it right and close the question

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function utf8_urldecode($str) {
    $str = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($str));
    return html_entity_decode($str,null,'UTF-8');;
  }
```